# Vaadin cannot be built after version upgrade because of license issue

Tags: vaadin

I have a personnal project using Vaadin.
If I run a

```
mvn clean package
```

in 23.2.6, it works perfectly.
If I update the pom.xml to go to version 23.3.6, I have the following issue :

```
Execution default of goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:23.3.6:build-frontend failed: Unable to validate the license, please check your internet connection. If you need to work offline then please go to https://vaadin.com/pro/validate-license?getOfflineKey=mid-ef05ac4a-266d8512 to retrieve an offline key. For troubleshooting steps, see https://vaadin.com/licensing-faq-and-troubleshooting.
```

But all I'm using is the core of Vaadin which price is free.
The pom looks like this in the plugin section :

> ```
>     <plugin>
>         <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
>         <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>         <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
>         <executions>
>             <execution>
>                 <goals>
>                     <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
>                     <goal>build-frontend</goal>
>                 </goals>
>             </execution>
>         </executions>
>     </plugin>
> ```

Has some library moved out of core ? How do I know which one ?
Is there an issue with my local environment ?

Comment: No, there should not have been licences required if it was not with 23.2. But you need to specify the correct dependency, there was a slight change somewhere.        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Comment: I already use vaadin-core. I also use vaadin-server, vaadin-push, vaadin-client-compiled, vaadin-themes, vaadin-spring-boot-starter and flow-server-production-mode. Which one is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (in the comments) mentioned artifacts (vaadin-server, vaadin-push,
vaadin-client-compiled, vaadin-theme) are all from previous versions
(e.g. 7 or 8) which both no longer have free support and need a license for versions newer than 7.7.17 or 8.14.3 respectively.

Rule of thumb: if you don't *know* you need a dep, remove it.  And don't
be shy about throwing things out - the compiler will complain, if
something is missing.

You are seeing the license checker error as there has been technical improvements in the checker between the versions.

Comment: My bad. I created my project in Vaadin 14 with the Spring Intitializr. I upgraded versions but never checked if some had become useless.